# Return users that meet a specific set of criteria in phpmyadmin database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi I'm fairly new to mysql and phpmyadmin so I've mostly just been learning from example queries, but I've had some trouble trying to construct my own simple query.

I'd like to search the phpmyadmin database I'm using for all users created between two dates, who belong to groups that don't contain "xyz" in the group name. There are two tables from which I'd be pulling from: `SITE_USER` and `SITE_TargetGroup`.

In `SITE_USER`the relevant columns are `name`, `surname`, `primarygroupID` (the ID of the user's group) and `createdAT`. In `SITE_TargetGroup` the relevant columns are `parentID` (the group's ID) and `name`. Here the `primarygroupID` and `parentID` will naturally be the same number (10) since I'm searching users who belong to the same types of groups but don't contain "xyz" in the group name. Sorry if this is confusing.

So far I've come up with this query:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.name, u.surname, u.email, tg.name AS group, u.createdAT AS date
FROM SITE_User u
    inner join SITE_TargetGroup tg
        on tg.userID = u.ID
WHERE u.primaryGroupID <> 10
    and u.createdAt BETWEEN ‘2014-04-09’ AND ‘2014-05-09
    and tg.name NOT LIKE ‘xyz’
GROUP BY dayofmonth(u.createdAT), month(u.createdAT)
ORDER BY dayofmonth(u.createdAT), month(u.createdAT)
```

But it returns the error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'group(tg.name) FROM SITE_User u inner join SITE_TargetGroup tg on tg.userID = u' at line 1

Could anyone advise on how to improve/construct a query to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: its `group_concat(tg.name)` and you in addition also will need group by clause. in addition provide some data in http://sqlfiddle.com along with your expected output.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty thank you, inputed both tables samples into sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3685/1. the output I'd like to get out is id, name, surname, email, createdAT, group name. For all users in groups with parentID 10 (excluding groups with parentID 10 whose names contain "xyz" in them, as illustrated in the sqlfiddle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK with the DDL to join the tables you need a common key between the tables.And looks like its

```
SITE_TargetGroup.parentID = SITE_USER.primarygroupID
```

So your query should look like

```
SELECT
u.ID,
u.name, 
u.surname, 
u.email, 
tg.name, 
date(u.createdAt)
FROM SITE_User u
inner join SITE_TargetGroup tg
on tg.parentID = u.primarygroupID
WHERE u.primaryGroupID <> 10
and u.createdAt BETWEEN '2014-04-09' AND '2014-05-09'
and tg.name NOT LIKE 'xyz'
```

Comment: ah had a feeling it might've been an issue with the table join, thank you!